# Saving Xcode Project to the Desktop

Tags: xcode, macos

When I open the Desktop folder where I saved my Xcode project, only a "main" or "swift" file is there, not the whole project. I need to zip the whole project and upload it for homework assignments.

Comment: You had to have saved all the files to the same location.  Sometimes it's easy to save new, or added, files to a different location when you create them.  Open the project again in Xcode, verify all your files are there, then select some of the files you think are missing and see where they're actually located.

Comment: What one file is missing from the desktop? You could search using spotlight to find it. Also - does the class notes have instructions on how to set up your projects? Following that might help you comply with the class requirements.

Answer (score -1):

go to your project folder press right button and  compress your folder and upload your required mail.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! That's what the OP *wants* to do, not what he is *able* to do right now. This answer doesn't help him in any way, and should be deleted (or drastically rewritten).